# Automatically find breakpoints in vector

Tags: r, spatial

I am currently working with vectors of hight-measurments i extracted for multiple spatial polygons from a raster.Those are stored as vectors of doubles.

As the polygons are not perfectly fitting the objects in the DEM, the extracted values still contain unwanted data i want to identify by finding the breakpoint in the vector data.

[image]

I am searching for a way to autmatically identify/split the lower(left) peaks, the "middle" part" and the high values.

Any hints?

Comment: Where would the split be in example 4?

Comment: You lost a lot of information by abandoning the spatial component of the data.  There exist many raster operations that can help you find and remove unwanted portions of the polygonal zones, assuming those portions tend to be spatially contiguous.  Perhaps you would be better off, then, returning to the rasters for a better and different analysis rather than pursuing your present approach.